# Custom initialization/cleanup in ANTLR3

Tags: java, antlr3

I need to do custom initialization & cleanup in most of my rules. Is there any way to avoid duplication in @init/finally blocks?

Currently my rules look like:

```
rule
@init { int mark = init(); } // Don't want to duplicate this!
...
;
finally { cleanup(mark); } // ... and that!
```

So, what I want is to declare somehow "this rule should make these standard init/cleanup calls" without copy-pasting @init/finally blocks everywhere.

I am using ANTLR3 and the target language is Java.

Comment: What is your target language?

Comment: @280Z28 target language is Java.

Comment: What are init()/cleanup() doing? There might be something else you can do overall

Comment: BTW: Slightly-off-topic, but you could do something like this with parser listeners in Antlr4 (and if you implemented the listener using a dynamic proxy you'd only write the pre/post code once)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a straightforward way to do what you want with ANTLR 3.  You couldn't even subclass the generated parser because all rule methods are declared final.

Probably the easiest to maintain would be either a pre-processing or code injection.  If the code, as in your example, is never really used by the rule actions, then you might be able to do it with code injection like AspectJ http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/ or Spring AOP http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/aop.html.  If it is more complicated in that your rules will access the `mark` variable, then you'd need to use some sort of preprocessor to add all the `inits` and `finallys`.

Personally, I'd copy and paste.  Generally parsers go through a lot of up front development and then only get minor bugfixes.  Any way you go there will be a certain amount of hassle with it.